# Dynamically created table via ajax breaks .on functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, live

I'm using `ajax` to dynamically create a table.  When someone enters a query, a table (data) is created and replaces the contents inside `#content-display`:

```
function searchQuery(query){    
    $.ajax({
      url: "search.php",
      data: {term: query},
      success: function(data){
          $("#content-display").html(data);
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });     
}
```

When someone clicks on an entry in the table, I want to alert the user of what they clicked on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#myTable tbody tr").on('click', function (){    
        alert($(this).children(":first")text());       
    });    
});
```

However the `.on` method is not working for me.  When I replace `.on` with `.live` it alerts the user of what they just clicked on but since `.live` is deprecated, how do I go about changing the syntax of the `.on` method to get it to work?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Is `#myTable` inside `#content-display`?  If so, that would break your handler when `#content-display` is replaced.

Comment: There is a missing dot in the code `...children(":first")text());` ==> `children(":first").text());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#content-display").on('click', '#myTable tbody tr', function (){    
        alert($(this).children(":first").text());       
    });    
});
```

Comment: @LedZeppelin. so change `#myTable` to the closest static element that holds that table. maybe `#content-display`?

Comment: Is `#myTable` dynamic as well as the rows being added? You want the nearest, _permanent_ dom element to bind to. Otherwise there is no reason for gdoron's code not to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
$("#myTable tbody tr").click(function() {});
```

instead?

Comment: Yes, I read the question, and it said nothing about the event type needing to be dynamic. Thanks for the negative vote though.

Comment: _"I'm using ajax to dynamically create a table. When someone enters a query, a table (data) is created and replaces the contents inside #content-display:"_. And by the way you didn't get any down vote(yet)...

Comment: The down vote was reversed. All that quoted piece says is that the table is being dynamically created. The author goes on to explain that the click event is the only one he's capturing.

So again, the author makes no mention of the event type being dynamic.

Comment: You didn't get votes at all. I can see the vote casts. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user)